# Objective Pascal - How do you ensure that you call a decendant's methods when cast as an acestor?

Tags: delphi, oop, inheritance, freepascal

I'm currently creating a small RPG engine. I've just gotten to the point of implementing a class tree for the game's objects and I'm not 100% sure which method directives I should use where and in what cases.

I've looked over the Free Pascal Complier's reference guide and various other internet resources but I'm still not confident.

The way I'm planning to implement the handling of game objects requires that categories of game objects have a common base class and will be stored in an array of that class, thus casting them as an ancestor.

What I mainly need to understand is how to ensure that when I call a class cast as one of it's ancestors that it calls the overloaded/overridden/reintroduced method of the actual class rather than that of the ancestor's.

Thanks for your time!

I'm quite happy to clarify/re-word anything here if I'm not being clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not "casting" when you put them into an array of their parent class, and you shouldn't be; that's not how inheritance and polymorphism works.

You create a virtual method in the parent (ancestor), and then each child inherits the parent's method and overrides it with their own specific behavior. When you call the parent method, polymorphism makes sure the proper method gets called.

Here's a quick (trivial) example of how something like this should be constructed. It's in the form of a console application, so that you can actually run it to see the output.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  // Base class
  TAnimal=class
    procedure Sit; virtual;   // Virtual keyword *necessary* for things to work
    procedure Speak; virtual; 
  end;

  // Descendent classes
  TDog=class(TAnimal)
    procedure Sit; override;    // Override keyword required here
    procedure Speak; override;  
  end;

  TCat=class(TAnimal)
    // No implementation of Sit, because cats don't sit on command
    procedure Speak; override;  // Override required here also
  end;

  // Array type to hold them, so we don't have to typecast anything
  TAnimalArray = array of TAnimal;

// Implementation of classes

{ TAnimal }
procedure TAnimal.Sit;
begin

end;

procedure TAnimal.Speak;
begin
  // Parent does nothing
end;

{ TCat }
procedure TCat.Speak;
begin
  inherited;
  WriteLn('Meow.');
end;

{ TDog }
procedure TDog.Sit;
begin
  inherited;
  WriteLn('Sitting down now.');
end;

procedure TDog.Speak;
begin
  inherited;
  Writeln('Woof! Woof!');
end;

// Test code to demonstrate use of inheritance and polymorphism    
var
  Animals: TAnimalArray;
  i: Integer;
  Pet: TAnimal;   // Variable that holds parent type (TAnimal)

const
  NumberOfAnimals = 5;

begin
  SetLength(Animals, NumberOfAnimals);

  // Fill array with a mix of both dogs and cats
  for i := 0 to High(Animals) do
  begin
    if Odd(i) then
      Animals[i] := TDog.Create
    else
      Animals[i] := TCat.Create;
  end;

  // Loop to use each one regardless of which type, by just accessing the
  // virtual Speak method they overrode from their parent class

  for Pet in Animals do
  begin
    Pet.Speak;
    Pet.Sit;     // Call method only defined for TDog
  end;

  WriteLn('');  // Blank line in console to separate loops.

  // If FreePascal doesn't support the enumeration (for..in) method, do it
  // using a counter:

  for i := 0 to High(Animals) do
  begin
    Animals[i].Speak;
    Animals[i].Sit;     // Call method only defined for TDog
  end;

  // In real life code, you'd loop through the array and free each one here.
  // In this test code, we're exiting right away, and there's really no point
  Readln;
end.
```

The above produces the output:

```
Meow.
Woof! Woof!
Sitting down.
Meow.
Woof! Woof!
Sitting down.
Meow.

Meow.
Woof! Woof!
Sitting down.
Meow.
Woof! Woof!
Sitting down.
Meow.
```

You can find a fairly complete discussion of Delphi's implementation of OOP at the [docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Classes_and_Objects). Although it's not FreePascal, much of it is compatible, and so it should be somewhat equivalent. I'm not aware of any documentation like it for FPC.

Comment: Ah, I see.
I didn't know that that storing descendent classes in an ancestor class didn't involve casting, I just assumed it was done in the background, thinking about it now it makes more sense.

The example illustrates what I need to do perfectly, thank you very much!

How would you then go about calling methods implemented by a descendant then? 
For example say that the class dog had implemented a new procedure called "Sit", would it be possible to call that?

Comment: Yes, of course. It would work the same way exactly. Declare it in the parent just as you did speak, provide a working implementation in the TDog class. If you call it on a TDog, the dog sits. If you call it on a TCat, the do nothing parent implementation gets called. I'll add that real quick, so you can see both.

Comment: I mean without implementing it in the parent because the inheritance tree in my game is going to be somewhat large, It's far from practical to implement every procedure in every class. Say, I had the the quite a few more animals inherit from TAnimal and each animal had either one or multiple procedures unique to itself.

Comment: You can do that, of course, but then you have to actually know what class you're dealing with and typecast to the proper type. You can't just say 'Animal.Swim' to a non-existent method in the parent; you'd have to know that the animal was a `TPolarBear` (or test first with 'if Animal is TPolarBear then', and then use `TPolarBear(Animal).Swim` instead (which defeats the whole purpose of inheritance and polymorphism in the first place).

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. You've made things much clearer, hopefully I can figure out a better way to implement the system.

Comment: Nice example Ken! I would never use arrays for objects though, TObjectlist or TObjectList<T> is a better fit...

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Neither would I, in a real life app. But the question was about Pascal classes (inheritance and polymorphism), not about whether arrays or another type would be better to store them. The array was simplicity, because it was quick and clean and didn't clutter the meaningful part of the code. :-) The same can be said for the comment I left just before the final `Readln;`. In a RW app, I'd do cleanup when I was finished.